# TFS Rest API - Passing parameters to Xaml Builds

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

We are looking to queue XAML builds problematically and using TFS Rest API for that.

To queue a build, we are posting to the Url,

```
https://{tfsinstance}/DefaultCollection/{teamproject}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0
```

as explained in the documentation https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build

The body of the request looks like

```
{
 "definition": { "id":7556 }, 
 "parameters": "{\"ExistingBuildNumber\":\"ReachClient.2146.8\"}" 
}
```

For XAML builds, The build does gets triggered with our call but the parameters we are passing are not passed to the queued build. Parameters gets passed to the new style TFS builds fine.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? The TFS Rest API doesn't mention a different mechanism for passing parameters to Xaml build?

We are using on-premise TFS server (TFS 2017 Update 2).

Comment: Which parameter are you actually using, did it support in XAML build? Suggest you to manually add the parameters in your XAML build definition and queue the build. See if the build works well with those parameters.

Comment: These are parameters that can be set at build queue time. I can't seem to set them using the TFS Rest API.

Answer (score 1):

The legacy XAML build system  is different with vNext build system. You couldn't  pass all arguments using Rest API. If you want to use Build definition id, reason and priority,you could use the [old REST API call](https://www.visualstudio.com/fr-fr/docs/integrate/api/xamlbuild/requests#request-a-build).

However for XAML build you could pass variable to build in the build definition directly when queue the build.

As a workaround, either use  `tfsbuild.exe` (to queue XAML builds) you can pass an additional argument like this:

```
&$tfsBuild.Exe start "url" project definition /requestedFor:"$buildRequestedFor" /queue
```

Or use TFS SDK [IBuildRequest.ProcessParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildrequest.processparameters(v=vs.120).aspx) which gets an XML formatted string representing all the process parameters for this build. A code snippet:

```
var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(collectionURL), new 
VssCredentials(true));
var res = await buildClient.QueueBuildAsync(new Build
            {
                Definition = new DefinitionReference
                {
                    Id = targetBuild.Id
                },
                Project = targetBuild.Project,
                SourceVersion = ChangeSetNumber,
                Parameters = buildArg

            });
            return res.Id.ToString();
```

More details for using TFS SDK, please refer this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpricket/2010/03/25/tfs2010-queuing-a-build-from-code-with-custom-process-parameter-values/).